# Spring mvc request handling error (404)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and i try to catch a request using handler method. The problem is i can not reach the handler method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gsaFeedRun", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(@ModelAttribute BaseFormBean formBean, BindingResult result,
HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Request grabbed!\n");
    getContext().getUserProfile().setLanguage(ProjectConstants.getLANGUAGE_TR());
    createSessionData(request);
    final java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("C:\\DEVEL\\xmlCollections.txt");
    readCollectionOfRoots(myFile); //Read the list of the desired root's lists file
    return null;
}
```

I've checked servlet.xml file and it seems to be ok. The request `localhost:8080/abc/gsaFeedRun` never answered and it displays on console:

```
***ERROR... page-not-found.jsp - 404 - /abc/gsaFeedRun
```

I need to clarify that there is no need to return any model view to the user. The controller is just supposed to do some calculations.

What could be the reason of that problem?

Comment: Please, use {code} tags

Comment: I've posted via mobile. Now editted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved. For anyone who faced this problem, the cause and solution of the problem:

yourProject-servlet.xml file (where your beans and other initializations have made) contains the statement:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your controller package" >
```

Where you inform the Spring framework about where are the methods/classes that were mapped to a request.So you need to create controller file (contains methods and/or classes with @Controller statement) under this package.

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible to send null.

The following return types are supported for handler methods:

A ModelAndView object (Servlet MVC or Portlet MVC), with the model implicitly enriched with command objects and the results of @ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods.

A Model object, with the view name implicitly determined through a RequestToViewNameTranslator and the model implicitly enriched with command objects and the results of @ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods.

A Map object for exposing a model, with the view name implicitly determined through a RequestToViewNameTranslator and the model implicitly enriched with command objects and the results of @ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods.

A View object, with the model implicitly determined through command objects and @ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods. The handler method may also programmatically enrich the model by declaring a Model argument (see above).

A String value which is interpreted as view name, with the model implicitly determined through command objects and @ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods. The handler method may also programmatically enrich the model by declaring a ModelMap argument (see above).

@ResponseBody annotated methods (Servlet-only) for access to the Servlet response HTTP contents. The return value will be converted to the response stream using message converters.

An HttpEntity or ResponseEntity object (Servlet-only) to access to the Servlet response HTTP headers and contents. The entity body will be converted to the response stream using message converters.

An HttpHeaders object to return a response with no body.

A Callable which is used by Spring MVC to obtain the return value asynchronously in a separate thread transparently managed by Spring MVC on behalf of the application.

A DeferredResult which the application uses to produce a return value in a separate thread of its own choosing, as an alternative to returning a Callable.

A ListenableFuture which the application uses to produce a return value in a separate thread of its own choosing, as an alternative to returning a Callable.
void if the method handles the response itself (by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse / RenderResponse for that purpose) or if the view name is supposed to be implicitly determined through a RequestToViewNameTranslator (not declaring a response argument in the handler method signature; only applicable in a Servlet environment).

Any other return type will be considered as single model attribute to be exposed to the view, using the attribute name specified through @ModelAttribute at the method level (or the default attribute name based on the return type's class name otherwise). The model will be implicitly enriched with command objects and the results of @ModelAttribute annotated reference data accessor methods.

From documentation: [RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

Comment: According to the document i conclude that i dont need any model and view returns as i only want to do some calculations apart from web corresponding to a request. am i right?

Comment: In my opinion, the simplest way is to use redirect in your return statement: redirect:http://myhost.com/some/arbitrary/path. Maybe you need and AJAX request and @ResponseBody to load some values in your HTML code  or just return the same view of the request

Comment: Redirect works. If possible try to read the documentation about how to use your requestsmapìngs. You need to have the redirected view created http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix

Comment: I have added   [return "redirect:/index-master-tr"]. that link is working while trying "localhost:8080/abc/index-master-tr". But i keep getting 404 error.